# Unable to mount /sites folder in Drupal Docker image

Tags: docker, drupal

I'm working on a Drupal project where I would like Drupal's core files to be in the Docker image, but the folders /sites /modules /themes /profiles to be loaded from an external source (local folders or in production an Azure BlockStore).

I'm running the following command in an attempt to get this up and running, but from what I can tell, the Drupal image overwrites the contents of the /sites folder which means that my settings.php file is removed, so when I visit the URL of the container I see the installation process.

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v modules:/var/www/html/modules -v profiles:/var/www/html/profiles -v sites:/var/www/html/sites -v themes:/var/www/html/themes drupal:8.5
```

Is there a way around this, a way to provide our own /sites folder?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in the command that you are running. You are not mounting local folders, but rather creating [named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) that store the specified directories of the container on the host.

If you want to specify [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), you have to use explicit paths and not names that are interpreted as named volumes.

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v $(pwd)/modules:/var/www/html/modules -v $(pwd)/profiles:/var/www/html/profiles -v /sites:/var/www/html/sites -v $(pwd)/themes:/var/www/html/themes drupal:8.5
```

Comment: Thanks, the volumes are now being correctly mapped, but it still doesn't solve the problem I'm having. Even with the /sites folder mapped correctly, viewing the container shows the Drupal install screen rather than using the database and settings defined in the /sites folder I've mapped